# Redirect customer to product page from where customer logged in to website Magento 2

Tags: magento, plugins, module, magento2, magento2.1

In Magento 2, I have a custom login form in Header.

If a customer is on the product page for eg :

http://www.testwebsite.com/catalog/product/view/id/10

and login from header form then customer should redirect to the same product page instead of Customer Dashboard.

I have tried plugin code from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134808/magento-2-redirect-customer-to-custom-page-after-login).

Below is my custom header form code -

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); 

$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$currenturl =  $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {?>
<div class="header-login-main">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost');?>" method="post" id="login-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input name="form_key" value="" type="hidden">
        <div class="header-login" style="">
            <span>Email</span>
            <input name="login[username]" id="email" class="input-text" title="Email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true" type="email">
        </div>
        <div class="header-login">
            <span>Password</span>
            <input name="login[password]" id="pass" class="input-text" title="Password" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" type="password">

        </div>
        <div class="header-login1">
            <button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span>Login</span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');?>" class="f-right" style="padding: 3px 5px;">Reset Your Password?</a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Plugin Code -

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class LoginPostPlugin
{

    /**
     * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath('/'); // Change this to what you want
        return $result;
    }

}
```

I want to redirect the customer to $currenturl. Link tutorial can be able to redirect to the home page. Please suggest what needs to be done to achieve to redirect the customer to the current page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below:

**Header Login Form :-**

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session'); 

$urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');
$currenturl =  $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();

if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {?>
<div class="header-login-main">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/loginPost');?>" method="post" id="login-form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input name="form_key" value="" type="hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name='referer' value="<?php echo $currenturl ?>">
        <div class="header-login" style="">
            <span>Email</span>
            <input name="login[username]" id="email" class="input-text" title="Email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true" type="email">
        </div>
        <div class="header-login">
            <span>Password</span>
            <input name="login[password]" id="pass" class="input-text" title="Password" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" type="password">

        </div>
        <div class="header-login1">
            <button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span>Login</span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword');?>" class="f-right" style="padding: 3px 5px;">Reset Your Password?</a>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

**Plugin Code : -**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;
class LoginPostPlugin
{
    protected $request;
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
       $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function getPostReferer()
    {
        return $this->request->getPostValue('referer');
    }

    /**
     * Change redirect after login to home instead of dashboard.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $result
     */
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
        $result)
    {
        $result->setPath($this->getPostReferer());
        return $result;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following code I have set the current url to the instant of $resultRedirect like this : ***$resultRedirect->setUrl($currenturl);***

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Account\Redirect as AccountRedirect;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Url as CustomerUrl;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\EmailNotConfirmedException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class LoginPost extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost {

    public function execute() {
        $urlInterface = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

        $sku = '24-MB01'; //Edit as per your product sku
        $_product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
        $currenturl = $_product->getProductUrl();

        if ($this->session->isLoggedIn() || !$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            //$resultRedirect->setPath('home');
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($currenturl);
            return $resultRedirect;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $login = $this->getRequest()->getPost('login');
            if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {
                try {
                    $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->authenticate($login['username'], $login['password']);
                    $this->session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);
                    $this->session->regenerateId();
                } catch (EmailNotConfirmedException $e) {
                    $value = $this->customerUrl->getEmailConfirmationUrl($login['username']);
                    $message = __(
                            'This account is not confirmed.' .
                            ' <a href="%1">Click here</a> to resend confirmation email.', $value
                    );
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
                    $message = __('Invalid login or password.');
                    $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid login or password.'));
                }
            } else {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('A login and a password are required.'));
            }
        }

        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        //$resultRedirect->setPath('home');
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($currenturl);
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am getting current url as http://www.testwebsite.com/customer/account/loginPost/  instead of product url

Comment: I have edited above answer by loading product url by sku. you need to set sku for that as per your requirement.

Comment: If I am not getting current URL so How can I get SKU of the current product page?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a plugin that receives the `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost` object you could get the referer URL like : `$subject->_redirect->getRefererUrl()`. Then return this URL

```
$productURL = $subject->_url->getUrl($subject->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
return $subject->_redirect($productURL);
```

I'm not 100% sure if this URL will actually be the URL you want but worth a try.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access protected property Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost\Interceptor::$_url in /var/www/magento/app/code/MyModule/Customization/Plugin/LoginPostPlugin.php:24

Comment: Right, I didnt know this property was protected. Then seems the best idea is to override LoginPost in your module and try to redirect to the referer URL there.

Comment: How can we use the protected property in the plugin ? should we use constructor and override it?

Comment: You cant use the protected property in the plugin. The solution link you provided in the original post has the example where they override the LoginPost class.